# how to add custom font to inkscape created svg

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg

excuse me for my question which may seem naive for many of you but I created svg file using inkscape and I am trying to include websafe font in it here is my svg file xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 488.15625 20.902084"
   height="79"
   width="1845">
 <defs>
<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam');</style>
</defs>
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(0,-276.09788)"
     id="layer1">
    <flowRoot
       transform="matrix(3.3345187,0,0,0.06651964,-9.573909,273.74952)"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;image-rendering:auto"
       id="flowRoot602"
       xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion604"><rect
           y="4.2857141"
           x="2.8571429"
           height="845.71429"
           width="1848.5714"
           id="rect606" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara6407"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:500;font-stretch:normal;font-size:14.9809618px;font-family:'URW Chancery L';-inkscape-font-specification:'URW Chancery L, Medium Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start" /></flowRoot>    <flowRoot
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
       id="flowRoot6397"
       xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion6399"><rect
           y="687.14288"
           x="702.85712"
           height="85.714287"
           width="11.428572"
           id="rect6401" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara6403"></flowPara></flowRoot>    <flowRoot
       style="fill:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px"
       id="flowRoot7660"
       xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion7662"><rect
           y="2.2284067"
           x="2.0203052"
           height="74.751289"
           width="1837.4675"
           id="rect7664" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara7666"></flowPara></flowRoot>    <text
       id="text7670"
       y="280.42926"
       x="0.53453898"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332;"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         id="tspan7676"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:1.76388884px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.26458332;"
         y="289.79303"
         x="0.53453898" /></text>
    <flowRoot
       style="fill:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px"
       id="flowRoot7680"
       xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion7682"><rect
           y="6.2690167"
           x="1.0101526"
           height="742.4621"
           width="1904.1376"
           id="rect7684" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara7686"></flowPara></flowRoot>    <text
       id="text7690"
       y="279.98032"
       x="172.13858"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:0.5;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:500;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.11527777px;font-family:'URW Chancery L';-inkscape-font-specification:'URW Chancery L, Medium Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-align:start;word-spacing:0.79374999px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#0000ff;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         y="279.98032"
         x="172.13858"
         id="tspan7688">Done reading your book</tspan><tspan
         id="tspan7696"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:500;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.11527777px;font-family:'URW Chancery L';-inkscape-font-specification:'URW Chancery L, Medium Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-align:start;word-spacing:0.79374999px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#008000;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         y="285.27197"
         x="172.13858">                     Make a legacy</tspan><tspan
         id="tspan7698"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:500;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.11527777px;font-family:'URW Chancery L';-inkscape-font-specification:'URW Chancery L, Medium Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-align:start;word-spacing:0.79374999px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#d40000;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         y="290.56366"
         x="172.13858">                                 Donate your book to someone else online </tspan><tspan
         id="tspan7700"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:500;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.11527777px;font-family:'URW Chancery L';-inkscape-font-specification:'URW Chancery L, Medium Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-align:start;word-spacing:0.79374999px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#550000;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         y="295.85532"
         x="172.13858">       Great way to make difference and save the environment</tspan></text>
    <text
       id="text7694"
       y="279.91547"
       x="1.889881"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         style="stroke-width:0.26458332"
         y="289.27924"
         x="1.889881"
         id="tspan7692" /></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

as you see I added:

```
<defs>
<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam');</style>
</defs>
```

but the font is not changing to the font I expect it stay the same old one.
what am I doing wrong? how to fix it?

Comment: This is not what web-safe font means, you're trying to load a custom font. Web-safe are the default fonts available across all devices.

Comment: Why don't you just convert your `text to path` in Inkscape and then save your svg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only changed one part of your code. You added the `@import` but there's not a single `font-family` that calls your custom font. As soon as you fix that, it should work. Something like `font-family: 'Kalam'` somewhere in your SVG.